# How to release DHCP lease on shutdown

Tags: networking, dual-boot, dhcp

I have several users with dual boot machines with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, both using wireless networking.  Both OSes go on different networks from each other.  When booting from Ubuntu to Windows, we're having a problem that the  DHCP lease for the IP used in Ubuntu is still active when Windows boots, so it's getting an IP in the wrong network.  I need to find a way to release the lease on shutdown so this does not occur.

Can someone please give me some guidance on this?

Comment: Does your DHCP server happen to be Windows Server, and are the two wireless networks in the same supergroup?

Comment: In the wrong network or simply different IP addresses; i.e. 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1.7? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The IP address is fine per physical system as long as multiple physical systems don't have the same IP.  But having both Windows and Ubuntu on the same system using the same IP won't hurt anything unless the system is actually running both at the same time like in a VM.  That is how I run it at home because I set an IP reservation for the MAC address and not the OS.

Comment: For me it's a problem because the Linux system is in an isolated VLAN on my company's network.  10.64.240.0.  Windows is on the main company VLAN.  The 2 VLANs do not have any connectivity between them.  With the Windows OS booted and the wireless port getting an IP from the wrong VLAN, it makes using WiFi impossible.

Comment: The problem then that you are bumping into here is that the lease time is handled by the server and not the client, so chances are releasing the IP from Ubuntu before rebooting is probably not going to work.  You can try running `sudo dhclient -r` right before you reboot and see if that works, but I have a feeling that it won't since it is the DHCP that gives out the leases and that they are stored in the dhcp.leases file on the server until they expire.  You will probably need to ask IT or someone if they can assign you reserved/static IPs that you can set statically on the system.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Our Wifi guru is going to coming to try to figure this out.